# Finding New York City tournaments as a visitor from Moscow

Tags: tournament

I am visiting New York City from Moscow. How can I find tournaments there?

Comment: If you are visiting New York City and like chess, the Marshall Chess Club is a natural place to visit, whether or not they are currently having a tournament: https://www.marshallchessclub.org/

Comment: It may be assumed but would be clearer to state specifically whether you want to enter or merely observe the tournaments.

Answer (score 5):

Most tournaments in the U.S. are not FIDE-rated, but there are some. Your best best are the more-common USCF-rated tournaments. You would have to join the USCF as part of that.

They have a list of tournaments [here](http://www.uschess.org/tlas/upcoming.php). Just pick the state you want, in this case, New York.